# How to send message to all member who's have a specific role on our server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i am make a server bot in discord.js  and i need a command from which i can send msg to all member who h X role.. where X be any random role in server

/roledm @admin hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to fetch the role from message.mentions.roles.  Then you need to filter client.guild.members by members that have such role. Once you have that, you can do a simple for loop to send a message to each of those members.

Comment: i can't understand loop part can you give some code ?\

Comment: Sure. Here a guide on for loops.  Do you have any code so we can see what you're doing wrong. Keep in mind this isn't a free coding service. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp